# What happens to floating point numbers in the absence of an FPU?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, floating-point, embedded

If you are programming with the C language for a microprocessor that does not have an FPU, does the compiler signal errors when floating point literals and keywords are encountered (0.75, float, double, etc)?

Also, what happens if the result of an expression is fractional?

I understand that there are software libraries that are used so you can do floating-point math, but I am specifically wondering what the results will be if you did not use one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A C implementation is required to implement the types `float` and `double`, and arithmetic expressions involving them. So if the compiler knows that the target architecture doesn't have floating-point ops then it must bring in a software library to do it. The compiler is allowed to link against an external library, it's also allowed to implement floating point ops in software by itself as intrinsics, but it must somehow generate code to get it done.

If it doesn't do so [*] then it is not a conforming C implementation, so strictly speaking you're not "programming with the C language". You're programming with whatever your compiler docs tell you is available instead.

You'd *hope* that code involving `float` or `double` types will either fail to compile (because the compiler knows you're in a non-conforming mode and tells you) or else fails to link (because the compiler emits calls to emulation routines in the library, but the library is missing). But you're on your own as far as C is concerned, if you use something that isn't C.

I don't know the exact details (how old do I look?), but I imagine that back in the day if you took some code compiled for x87 then you might be able to link and load it on a system using an x86 with no FPU. Then the CPU would complain about an illegal instruction when you tried to execute it -- quite possibly the system would hang depending what OS you were running. So the worst possible case is pretty bad.

> what happens if the result of an expression is fractional?

The actual result of an expression won't matter, because the expression itself was either performed with integer operations (in which case the result is not fractional) or else with floating-point operations (in which case the problem arises before you even find out the result).

[*] or if you fail to specify the options to make it do so ;-)

Comment: I see.  So, even if a processor cannot handle floating point calculations natively, the C compiler MUST provide the software to do this.  Am I correct?  When you say provide the software library, does that mean that I, as the programmer, must make explicit function calls to do floating point math, or can the compiler handle float a = 3.0f/4.0f for me 'behind-the-scenes'?

Comment: @jrahhali: The compiler is required to understand and implement `float a = 3.0f/4.0f;`.

Answer (score 4):

Floating-point is a required part of the C language, according to the C standard. If the target hardware does not have floating-point instructions, then a C implementation must provide floating-point operations in some other way, such as by emulating them in software. (All calculations are just functions of bits. If you have elementary operations for manipulating bits and performing tests and branches, then you can compute any function that a general computer can.)

A compiler could provide a subset of C without floating-point, but then it would not be a standard-compliant C compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Software floating point can take two forms:

- a compiler may generate calls to built-in floating point functions directly - for example the operation `1.2 * 2.5` may invoke (for example) `fmul( 1.2, 2.5 )`,
- alternatively for architectures that support an FPU, but for which some device variants may omit it, it is common to use FPU emulation.  When an FP instruction is encountered an invalid instruction exception will occur and the exception handler will vector to code that emulates the instruction.

FPU emulation has the advantage that when the same code is executed on a device with a real FPU, it will be used automatically and accelerate execution.  However without an FPU there is usually a small overhead compared with direct software implementation, so if the application is never expected to run on an FPU, emulation might best be avoided is the compiler provides the option.

Software floating point is very much slower that hardware supported floating point.  Use of fixed-point techniques can improve performance with acceptable precision in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, such microprocessor comes along either with a driver-package or even with a complete BSP (board-support-package, consisting of drivers and OS linked together), both of which contain FP library routines.

The compiler replaces every floating-point operation with an equivalent function call. This should be taken into consideration, especially when invoking such operations iteratively (inside a `for` / `while` loop), since the compiler cannot apply loop-unrolling optimization as a result.

The result of not including the required libraries within the project would be linkage errors.

Comment: This answers the question in my comment to Steve Jessop.  Thanks